# What is the best way to get data from multiple web services in ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a website that consume data from more than five different web services on different servers. And I don't know what is the best way to start the work...
Example:
   I have to load information from:

1. http://api.example1.com
2. http://api.example2.com
3. http://api.example3.com
4. and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting that data on the same route, you will probably do something like this (from the Ember docs):

```
        export default Ember.Route.extend({
          model() {
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
              songs: this.store.findAll('song'),
              albums: this.store.findAll('album')
            });
          }
        });
```

To interact with those API's, I'm assuming you will have API keys and the like to deal with as well.  In that case, you will want to run 'ember generate adapter resourceName' for each of those API's you interact with and fill them out as seen below (taken from the [Ember Data docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html)--and I'm assuming you are using Ember Data):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com',
  headers: {
    "API_KEY": "secret key",
    "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I have reviewed the documentation about it. And this is the best way to resolve this kind of issues... Everything is working well I'm consuming all my apis.

Answer (score 1):

Ember.RSVP.allSettled, this [API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_allSettled) maybe suitable.